# How to check if email or username are registered

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to check if email is already in database too but I doesnt work with this code.

I am using this code to check for the name:

```
   $checkDB = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checkDB);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $errorName = 'Това име е заето';
        $mainError = true;
    }
```

Comment: Add `email` condition too in `where` clause..

Comment: I forgot to meantion that i did that. It is not the problem.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, Do you mean `AND email='$email'` ?

Comment: Update your code then. Also "It doesnt work with this code" is an unclear explanation of your problem. What EXACTLY is going wrong? Are you getting errors? Are you getting incorrect results, if yes, what of results? Etc.

Comment: @RayonDabre No, I meant `OR` because a search can be made with username or email, like whether a user exists or not in the database holding that particular username or email. I'm not sure what OP is trying to achieve, the question is not clear.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, Ooh yes, I thought he is dealing with `userName` and `Password`. In that case `OR` would not be accurate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will works

```
$w=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where user_name='$name'");
$num=mysqli_num_rows($w);

if($num>=1)
{
echo "Record Already Exists";   
}
else
 {
  echo "No Record";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is set a constraint in your database for unique usernames and e-mail addresses. Then, try to do an insert and catch the exception when it fails. Otherwise, you could have a condition where nearly simultaneous users try to register at the same time, and between your SELECT and INSERT statements, the username or e-mail address might be used by someone else.

`ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE INDEX email (email);`

or you can check both with SQL first:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>=1){
    $errorName = "Username or email already exist.";
    $mainError = true;
}
```

Comment: Well they are set to UNIQUE.

Comment: Ok, than you can catch it, if you insert the Data.
Or you can check E-Mail and Username first, view my editied answer.